# Integrating custom google map saved location to custom google map

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have html code for Google maps. I would like to add my custom location to the code but i cant figure out how. i did some research and to add custom locations you need to add kml file. I do not know how to do so. can someone help me? Bellow is my map code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Change Layer on Zoom in Google Fusion Tables</title>
<style>

#map_canvas { height: 550px; width: 825px; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="address" ></input><input onclick="geocode_address();" type="button" value="Zipcode"></input>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?…
<script>

var map, countyTable, tractTable, ctyLayer;
var tractLayers = [];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function geocode_address() {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value…

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.locati…
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+8);
});
}


function addClickHandler(FTLayer) {
google.maps.event.addListener(FTLayer, "click", function(event) {
infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset:event… 
content:event.infoWindowHtml,
position:event.latLng
});
infowindow.open(map);
});
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(… {
center: new google.maps.LatLng( 36.315125,-95.273437…
zoom: 4,
mapTypeId: "roadmap",
streetViewControl: false
});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the kml example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Example</name>
<description><![CDATA[Location update]]></description>
<Style id="style1">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href></href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="style3">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href></href></href>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="style2">
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href></href></href>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>Chase</name>
<description><![CDATA[<div dir="ltr&quo
```

I have been trying to figure out how to do it can you help me?